# Find salesperson with highest sales per client

Tags: excel, excel-formula, office365, excel-365

I have two sheets:

(a) Sales Data

| Client | Sales Agent | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | Mike Georgi | 1,000 |
| Apple | Mike Georgi | 2,000 |
| Apple | Michelle Da | 4,000 |

(b) Receivables Data

| Client | Sales Agent | Value |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Apple | **Michelle** | 7,000 |

The data on column A & C are settled, but I have to fix second Column with Sales Agent data; **basically I have to find the agent with most sales per client in column B**.
The data in column A are spilled. I'm trying to do this with a formula, without VBA.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a pivot table where you put in column "Client" and row "Sales Agent", and put in values your variable "Value". This will output a table with the total value (total sale) for each sale agent and for each client.
Would that answer your question?

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Well actually no. I will need to find the agent with most sales per each client as above.